# Are post-apocalyptic settings SciFi?

Tags: discussion, scope

What are post-apocalyptic stories? Are they SciFi, or more Fantasy or something of it's own? Examples that come to mind are *[Metro 2033](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metro_2033_%28book%29)* and *[Mad Max](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mad_Max)*.